# Apple Devices with magnetometer?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ipod-touch, ipod

Which apple mobile devices have a magnetometer?  I thought that the iPod touch had one but I think I am mistaken.

Do all devices with GPS have a magnetometer?  Do all devices with a magnetometer have a GPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPhone 3GS and iPhone 4.

Comment: The iPad also has a digital compass.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to check is with [this class method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CLLocationManager/headingAvailable). I wrote a little app and ran it on a few devices I had lying around, and it looks like only iPhone 3GS+ (so iPhone 4 as well) have one right now, although I've seen [sketchy evidence](http://modmyi.com/forums/ipod-touch-general-chat/733331-compass-application-ipod-touch-4g.html) that pieces of the Compass app exist in touches.