# Why am I not reading any magnetic field values with this simple code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, magnetometer

**Game.m**

```
#import "Game.h"
#import "CoreMotion.h"

@implementation Game

- (id) init 
{
    self = [super init];

    self.stopButtonPressed = NO;

    return self;
}
-(void) play
{
     CMMotionManager *motionManager;
     motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
     motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.f/10.f;
     [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                                        withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error)
                                        {
                                          NSLog(@"--------------> %i %i", motionManager.deviceMotionActive , motionManager.deviceMotionAvailable);

                                          NSLog(@"Degrees : %F",atan(motion.magneticField.field.y/fabs(motion.magneticField.field.x)) * 180.0 / M_PI);
                                        }
     ];
}
```

**MyViewController.m**

```
#import "MyViewController.h"
#import "Game.h"

@interface MyViewController()
{
    Game *game;
}
@end

@implementation MyViewController

-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    game = [[Game alloc] init];
}

- (IBAction)playPressed:(UIButton *)sender 
{
    // using a separate thread
    //[game performSelectorInBackground:@selector(play) withObject:nil];

    // not using a separate thread
    [game play] ;
}

- (IBAction)stopPressed:(UIButton *)sender 
{
    game.stopButtonPressed = YES;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the magnetic field value is not available immediately after you call the method `startDeviceMotionUpdates`. You need to try to retrive the value in a later point (i.e. using a `NSTimer` and checking for updates.

Although this should work it isn't a good practice. If you only need the magnetic field value you should take a look at the documentation of `CMMotionManager` and use the method [startMagnetometerUpdatesToQueue:withHandler:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CMMotionManager/startMagnetometerUpdatesToQueue%3awithHandler%3a) like the following:

```
[motionManager startMagnetometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] withHandler:^(CMMagnetometerData *magnetometerData, NSError *error) {
  CMMagneticField field = magnetometerData.magneticField;
  NSLog(@"x: %f  y:%f  z:%f", field.x, field.y, field.z);
}];
```

cheers,
anka

Comment: I will try that but I don't want to use the magnetometerData's raw values but rather the deviceMotion's processed calibrated data, as in : `NSOperationQueue *myQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    CMMotionManager *motionManager;
    motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:myQueue
                                       withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error){NSLog(@"Value of X : %F",motion.magneticField.field.x)}` will this code work?

Comment: I tried that (I've edited my original post as well to reflect the changes I made), the app doesn't crash, but I get nothing. Not even a log output on the console.

Comment: Hi, use the following operation queue `[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]` and do not forget to set the update rate with `motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.f/10.f;`.

Comment: I've re-edited my post to the current code I'm using but I still get nothing. Sorry but I'm fairly new to Obj-C.. :)

Comment: The code `while(!self.stopButtonPressed)` is unnecessary because the block will be called repeatedly depending on your update interval. You could just use `if(!self.stopButtonPressed)`.  Also try to check the state of your motion manager with `NSLog(@"-------------->   %i %i", motionManager.deviceMotionActive , motionManager.deviceMotionAvailable);` and see if magnetometer is available.

Comment: I get"   --------------> 0 1 " I goes that means device motion is active (0) but device motion is not available (1) for some weird reason ?

Comment: Now I found your problem: You are calling your `play` method in background. Avoid this and let it run on the main thread and the motion updates should work too.

Comment: by the way, I'm not using an NSTimer, I'm only using the code presented on my original post

Comment: Have a look at the latest edit of my original post. This is what I get now : --------------> 1 1
          Degrees : NAN

Comment: You get NAN because you are dividing by 0.

Comment: Obviously. Because I'm not reading any magnetic field values. The question is why?

Answer (score 1):

You need to hold onto the `CMMotionManager`. So make an instance variable for it. For example:

#### Game.m

```
#import "Game.h"
#import "CoreMotion.h"

@interface Game ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) CMMotionManager *motionManager;
@end

@implementation Game

@synthesize motionManager = _motionManager;

- (id) init 
{
    self = [super init];

    self.stopButtonPressed = NO;

    return self;
}
-(void) play
{
     self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
     self.motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.f/10.f;
     [self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                                             withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error)
                                             {
         NSLog(@"--------------> %i %i", self.motionManager.deviceMotionActive , self.motionManager.deviceMotionAvailable);
         NSLog(@"Degrees : %F",atan(motion.magneticField.field.y/fabs(motion.magneticField.field.x)) * 180.0 / M_PI);
                                             }
     ];
}
```

The problem is that your `CMMotionManager` that you're creating is being deallocated at the end of the `play` method since nothing is holding onto it. So the handler never gets called back because your motion manager has gone away.

Comment: Have you tried looking at `startMagnetometerUpdatesToQueue:withHandler:`?

Comment: No because it is supposed to return raw biased magnetic field values where as the DeviceMotion class (or the CLLocationManager) returns already processed unbiased values, according to documentation..

Answer (score 0):

BTW One possibility is that the device you are running may not even have a magnetometer. See [magnetometer-for-compass-on-ipod-touch-4g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247167/magnetometer-for-compass-on-ipod-touch-4g)  Where I point to [apple-devices-with-magnetometer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227272/apple-devices-with-magnetometer)

Comment: Just checking!  Its been missed before.